# Orchard content export/Import

Tags: sql, orchardcms

How to export / import only Content element(example like Page,Custom widget etc) in orchard CMS database of one server(Dev) to the orchard cms database of another server(QA/Production) using SQL?

I did export/import by creating recipe It is working pretty fine, but I need to transfer only page from one Orchard instance to another.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with exporting using Orchard's importexport feature?

Comment: Export/import feature is working fine.but there is no option to select particular element. I am looking for way to move only a particular content element like page , layout etc.

Comment: you can always just edit the file manually to remove all the other pages that you export. if you are writing code you could write a small module that enables you to export one particular item

Comment: I edited the file manually That worked for me. and also I have wriiten SQL query to updated it from MSSQL, Thanks for your time and help Hazza.